# ASP.net MVC : Create MVC 5 Application using EF6 with Code First and Existing Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have to create an application in MVC 5 using EF6. I have already created the schema for the database in SQL Server 2012 and now I want to query this in my app.

The workflow that seems fit is Code First with Existing Database and I have tried to follow below resources but they are a little confusing to me as I am a beginner.

Is there a way I can still use my DB schema in SQL server and go ahead with Code First approach using generated data models from DB.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: yes you can use Fluent API to map classes(in your code are your tables).create a class for each table  then map then class  with Fluent API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can reverse engineer code first from existing DB schema. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx) you can find instructions how do do it. Since you already created your DB schema you can start from point **3. Reverse Engineer Model.**
This process will create for you a DbContext, POCO classes for the tables you selected in the wizard and the mappings. You can use it to query your DB.

When your DB schema changes in the future you can either regenerate POCO classes again or simply edit them by hand (if column type changed simply change the property type, if new column was added add new property to your class). Most devs use reverse engineer code first from existing DB only as a starting point when they need to target existing legacy database. After initial creation all future changes in schema are reflected by manually editing the classes that were originally generated by the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But in this case how do i update the POCO classes if i have updated DB (lets say changing the data type of column or adding a new column).